# Loading dted data using gdal with g++ in solaris 10?

Tags: c++, gdal, solaris-10

I want to load Digital Terrain Elevation(DTED) data using gdal using g++ in solaris 10. In solaris 10, the application with cc compiler loads the data successfully, but when I am using netbeans and g++. the application successfully reads Digital Terrain Elevation(DTED) data but application crashes at `GetGeoTranformation(double *)` when I print `GDALdataset->getDriver()->GetDescription()`. This function is working fine in cc. If I comment the line, the application crashes at `GDALDataset->GetRasterBand(1)`, and error prints `ld.so.1 fatal reallocation error symbol_ZN11GDALDataset13GetRasterBandIOEi reference symbol not found`

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind posting a part of the code which uses GDAL?  There could be a few issues.  Off the top of my head...

1. GDAL `GetRasterBand` starts at 1 when indexing.  It seems like your snippet you provided does that.
2. GDAL requires that you initialize the drivers with `GDALAllRegister()`.
3. Most GDAL functions return NULL when they return without data.  You may want to test that before passing it into another function to prevent potential seg faults.
4. What does cc point to? I would check the symbolic link with something like

   - `which cc`
   - `ls -la /usr/bin/cc` (Solaris is Unix, not Linux so forgive me if I am wrong).